# Table of Contents style fit to part style

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents

I am using `titlesec` and `TikZ` to customize my `\part` style.

I would appreciate to use the `\part` style for the `\tableofcontents` title.

Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Do you want the ToC title to be generated as with `\part` or do you just want to apply the same formatting. If the former, see my answer below; in the latter case, add to your question the relevant settings of your definitions.

Comment: I want to apply the same formatting to my ToC title as the `\part` title. I used a style very similar to this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159551/customizing-part-style-with-tikz.