# Change part environment to chapter environment

Tags: chapters, tikz-styles

This question builds from the post [customizing-part-style-with-tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159551/customizing-part-style-with-tikz/).

1. How do I go about making this heading work for the Chapters?
2. How to change the **PART** name that shows up in the number to **SOLUTION**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the hard work is [done by Gonzalo already](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159555/11232). You have to just change the `part` to `chap` and `PART` to `SOLUTION` in his code.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fourier}% change to lmodern if fourier is no available
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}

\newcommand\chapnumfont{% font specification for the number
  \fontsize{380}{130}\color{myblueii}\selectfont%
}

\newcommand\chapnamefont{% font specification for the name "PART"
  \normalfont\color{white}\scshape\small\bfseries
}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-13cm]current page.north east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=18cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {\thechapter};%
  \node[
      anchor=south east,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-20pt]chaptop.south)
    {\chapnumfont\thechapter};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {\chapnamefont SOLUTION};
  \node[
      anchor=north east,
      align=right,
      inner xsep=0pt] at ([yshift=-0.5cm]chapname.east|-chapnum.south)
  {\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\raggedleft#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-13cm]current page.north east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=18cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {};%
  \node[
      anchor=south east,minimum width=2in,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-20pt]chaptop.south)
    {};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {};
  \node[
      anchor=north east,
      align=right,
      inner xsep=0pt] at ([yshift=-0.5cm]chapname.east|-chapnum.south)
  {\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\raggedleft#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{3.5in}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{0pt}{3.5in}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Theory and Application of Continuous-Time Signals and Systems}
Some text comes here.
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution, but in the table of contents now, the text overlaps into the blue areas.  How to work around this issue?

Comment: @Joe Add `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{3.5in}` to your preamble. However, it is better to add a re-definition of numberless chapters in the same way above and adjust the spacing for it too.