# Header and Section Fancy Styles

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer

How can I modify the code generated by Mr. Gonzalo Medina found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159551/customizing-part-style-with-tikz/), to get the header, section and subsection to look like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{52,177,201}
\definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,45,97}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}

\newcommand\chapnumfont{% 
  \fontsize{380}{130}\color{myblueii}\selectfont%
}

\newcommand\chapnamefont{%
  \normalfont\color{white}\scshape\small\bfseries
}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\stepcounter{chapshift}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-13cm]current page.north east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=18cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {\thechapter};%
  \node[
      anchor=south east,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-20pt]chaptop.south)
    {\chapnumfont\thechapter};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {};
  \node[
      anchor=north east,
      align=right,
      inner xsep=0pt] at ([yshift=-0.5cm]chapname.east|-chapnum.south)
  {\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\raggedleft#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-13cm]current page.north east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=18cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {};%
  \node[
      anchor=south east,minimum width=2in,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-20pt]chaptop.south)
    {};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {};
  \node[
      anchor=north east,
      align=right,
      inner xsep=0pt] at ([yshift=-0.5cm]chapname.east|-chapnum.south)
  {\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\raggedleft#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{3.5in}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{0pt}{3.5in}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{plain}

\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

\newcommand\BoxColor{myblueii}

\def\subsectiontitle{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\def\subsectiontitle{#1}}

\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}}
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textcolor{mybluei} \rightmark%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=-1pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=28cm,align=center,anchor=north east]
  at ($ (current page.north east) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{18cm}{%
   \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\thechapter.\leftmark \hspace{2cm}\rightmark\hspace{2cm}\thesubsection~\subsectiontitle}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textcolor{mybluei}\leftmark%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=28cm,align=center,anchor=north west]
  at ($ (current page.north west) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{18cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\thechapter.\leftmark \hspace{2cm}\rightmark\hspace{2cm}\thesubsection~\subsectiontitle}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
\newcommand{\footrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.5pt}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape Foot 1}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\bfseries Foot 2}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape Foot 3}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% 
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{This is how it all began}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{Sub Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]

\chapter{This is how it all ended}
\section{Time to say "Goodbye"}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tikz isn't required for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one option (notice that now `titlesec` is loaded with both `explicit` and `calcwidth`) options so the title width can be accessed to control the rule width:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{52,177,201}
\definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,45,97}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}

\newcommand\chapnumfont{% 
  \fontsize{380}{130}\color{myblueii}\selectfont%
}

\newcommand\chapnamefont{%
  \normalfont\color{white}\scshape\small\bfseries
}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\stepcounter{chapshift}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-13cm]current page.north east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=18cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {\thechapter};%
  \node[
      anchor=south east,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-20pt]chaptop.south)
    {\chapnumfont\thechapter};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {};
  \node[
      anchor=north east,
      align=right,
      inner xsep=0pt] at ([yshift=-0.5cm]chapname.east|-chapnum.south)
  {\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\raggedleft#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-13cm]current page.north east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=18cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {};%
  \node[
      anchor=south east,minimum width=2in,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-20pt]chaptop.south)
    {};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {};
  \node[
      anchor=north east,
      align=right,
      inner xsep=0pt] at ([yshift=-0.5cm]chapname.east|-chapnum.south)
  {\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\raggedleft#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{3.5in}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{0pt}{3.5in}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\addtolength{\titlewidth}{2pc}\normalfont\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\colorbox{myblueii}{\parbox{2cm}{\strut\color{white}\hfill\thesection}}}
  {1em}{#1}
  [{\titleline*[l]{\color{myblueii}\titlerule[2pt]}}]
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\addtolength{\titlewidth}{2pc}\normalfont\large\sffamily}
  {\colorbox{myblueii}{\parbox{2cm}{\strut\color{white}\hfill\thesubsection}}}
  {1em}{#1}
  [{\titleline*[l]{\color{myblueii}\titlerule[2pt]}}]

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{plain}

\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

\newcommand\BoxColor{myblueii}

\def\subsectiontitle{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\def\subsectiontitle{#1}}


\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{{\color{myblueii}%
\hrule width\headwidth height\headrulewidth depth\headrulewidth}}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize#1}{}}
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\colorbox{myblueii}{\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries\strut\quad\thepage\quad}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textcolor{mybluei} \rightmark%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=-1pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=28cm,align=center,anchor=north east]
  at ($ (current page.north east) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{18cm}{%
   \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\thechapter.\leftmark \hspace{2cm}\rightmark\hspace{2cm}\thesubsection~\subsectiontitle}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textcolor{mybluei}\leftmark%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=28cm,align=center,anchor=north west]
  at ($ (current page.north west) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{18cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\thechapter.\leftmark \hspace{2cm}\rightmark\hspace{2cm}\thesubsection~\subsectiontitle}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
\newcommand{\footrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.5pt}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape Foot 1}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\bfseries Foot 2}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape Foot 3}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% 
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{This is how it all began}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Sub Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter{This is how it all ended}
\section{Time to say "Goodbye"}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

An image for the resulting section and subsection titles:

[image]

An image of the header for an odd-numbered page:

[image]